# How to check that Verilog enum is valid?

Tags: enums, system-verilog

If I receive an enum:

```
my_cmd cmd = my_cmd'(value_from_bus);
```

How do I easily check that `cmd` is a valid cmd?

```
typedef enum int {
  ADD = 1,
  SUBTRACT = 3,
  MULTIPLY = 7
} my_cmd;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also use `$cast` to check if it is valid, and copy at the same time.
So instead of doing: `cmd = my_cmd'(value_from_bus);`, you can do this:

```
if ($cast(cmd, value_from_bus))
    $display("Valid: %s", cmd.name());
else
    $display("Invalid");
```

Example on [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/D8n)

Answer (score 3):

You can use enum's **name()** function:

```
  if (cmd.name() == "")
    $display("%0d is bad", cmd);
  else
    $display("%s:%0d is good", cmd.name(), cmd);
```

Example on [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/VSc)

Comment: Interesting! Although I doubt it is synthesizable.

Comment: In Quartus Prime, this failed in analysis: "name is not declared under this prefix"